# I am writing a code which builds a decision tree and spits out the tree in the form of a code of if-else loops

Tags: python, decision-tree

I am able to generate the correct if else loops. But i am not able to adjust the indentation. Is there any way of correctly indenting it?

Comment: Please show your code, otherwise we can’t help you.

Comment: Are you adding stuff to a string? Can you think of any similar way to add some more stuff to the string?

Comment: Change your title to ask a question or explain the problem instead of telling us what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an indentation level that matches the decision tree depth, you should be able to just prepend four spaces for each level of indentation.